# Modify class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

```
<span class="here one-two-del-del other1">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-aaa o2ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-dsf other3">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-213 o4ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-sdf other5">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-sdff o6ther">test</span>

<span class="set one-two-aaaa">set 1</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-bb-fff">set 2</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-vcvc">set 3</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-fgdfg-dfgfd-fgf">set 4</span> <br />​

​$('.set').click(function(){
  $('#here').???
})​
```

i would like - if i click on .set then this should get own class and replace in all .here.

For example if i click on *set 2* then all span with class .here should be:

```
​<span class="here one-two-bb-fff other1">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-bb-fff o2ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-bb-fff other3">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-bb-fff o4ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-bb-fff other5">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-bb-fff o6ther">test</span>
```

i cant use removeClass because i dont know how is the current class. If i use .attr('class', 'new') then this replace all class, but i must still have class other1, o2ther etc

http://jsfiddle.net/NNhDd/

Maybe i must use regular expression?

Comment: having several class attributes makes your document _invalid_.

Comment: you don't need multiple 'class' attributes [check this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm).

Comment: Not a valid mark-up. You can't use class attribute more then once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<span class="here one-two-del-del other1">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-aaa o2ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-dsf other3">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-213 o4ther">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-sdf other5">test</span>
<span class="here one-two-sdff o6ther">test</span>

<br />

<span class="set one-two-aaaa">set 1</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-bb-fff">set 2</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-vcvc">set 3</span> <br />
<span class="set one-two-fgdfg-dfgfd-fgf">set 4</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.set').click(function () {
    var replaceWith = $(this).attr('class');
    // Remove the "set " from replaceWith
    replaceWith = replaceWith.replace(/set ?/g, '');

    $('.here').each(function () {
        var newClass = $(this).attr('class');
        newClass = newClass.replace(/one-two-[^ $]+/, '');
        newClass = newClass + ' ' + replaceWith;
        // Now set the new class
        $(this).attr('class', newClass);
    });
})
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NNhDd/3/